# How to set Eclipse CDT to index / resolve std files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v; //Symbol vector could not be resolved

    return 0;
}
```

The IDE complains about "vector": *Symbol vector could not be resolved*.

If I right click the "vector" keyword -> Source -> Add Include, nothing happens.

If I manually add `#include <vector>`, then everything is just fine, the  file is indexed and I can use its member functions.

However, I expect the IDE to generate these include files for me, instead of manually adding them. How to setup eclipse to work like this?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Eclipse CDT Neon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if another file in your project already includes `<vector>`.

The way **Add Include** works is it searches the project's **index** for the name it's invoked on. If it finds a binding (function, type, etc.) corresponding to that name in the index, it sees what file declares that binding, and then includes that file for you.

For this to work, the binding corresponding to the name must be in the index already. For bindings declared in files external to your project (such as standard library headers), that will only be the case if the external file is already included by some file in your project.

Answer (score 1):

@HighCommander4 - I noticed, through practice, the indexer behaves like in your description. There must be another file which already includes `vector` in order to have it in the index.

Given this behavior we can do the following:

1. One workaround is to have a dummy cpp file including `<bits/stdc++.h>`. Most of the stl headers are there. The header is available for GCC. For MSVC we can simply copy the content of  into this dummy cpp file.
2. Another workaround is to add a linked folder to the location of the stl, in my case this is `/usr/include/c++/5`. In this case the whole stl library gets indexed from the very beginning.